# Can't wrap my head around parallel_for from tbb

Tags: c++, concurrency, tbb

```
#include <tbb/concurrent_vector.h>
#include <tbb/parallel_for.h>
#include <random>

#define N 1000000

int main()
{
    tbb::concurrent_vector<u_int32_t> v(N);

    std::mt19937 mt;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<u_int32_t> dist(0,499);

    tbb::parallel_for( tbb::blocked_range<tbb::concurrent_vector<u_int32_t>>(v.begin(),v.end()),[&]{return dist(mt);});

    return(0);

}
```

I don't get why this is isn't working, It's my understanding that the interface for this `parallel_for` should include the startpoint of the container, the endpoint and the size of the step that should be performed at each iteration of the loop, the last argument it's the function that it will be executed.

now `tbb::blocked_range` it's used to split the container ( right ? ), so it should be useful in this case, I can't get this to work and I don't get why this just doesn't work with iterators in a much simpler way ...

Comment: What you want to do is `tbb::parallel_for(0, N, [&](int i){v[i]  = dist(mt);});` ?

Comment: @yohjp not really, I would like to use iterators, v.begin() and v.end() or tbb::blocked_range, I would like to avoid the use of constants and try to implement this with reusable components and try to be more c++-ish

Answer (score 5):

> I would like to use iterators, v.begin() and v.end() or tbb::blocked_range, I would like to avoid the use of constants and try to implement this with reusable components and try to be more c++-ish

TBB has `parallel_for_each` function template for iterator based loop.

```
#include "tbb/parallel_for_each.h"

tbb::parallel_for_each(v.begin(), v.end(),
  [&](u_int32_t& e) {
    e = /*...*/; 
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

What you really want seems to be:

```
tbb::parallel_for( tbb::blocked_range<tbb::concurrent_vector<u_int32_t>::iterator>(v.begin(),v.end()),[&](tbb::blocked_range<tbb::concurrent_vector<u_int32_t>::iterator>&){return dist(mt);});
```

Maybe a `typedef` is necessary here and there :D

```
int main() {
    typedef tbb::concurrent_vector<u_int32_t> vector;
    vector v(N);

    std::mt19937 mt;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<u_int32_t> dist(0,499);

    typedef tbb::blocked_range<vector::iterator> range;
    tbb::parallel_for( range(v.begin(),v.end()),[&](range& r){for(auto& i: r) { i = dist(mt); } });

    return(0);
}
```

is fairly better :D

Comment: apparently there is no assignment, the vector is full of zeros after the parallel_for

Comment: Apparently, your lambda has to iterate the range it receives, not return a value. Editing now...

Comment: thanks, now it looks like it's working, so the parallel_for doesn't really performs an action for each iteration, it just splits a data structure in pieces and gives you an iterator ?

Comment: Right.  The "range" form of parallel_for is generic to the point that it does not even know what an iteration is.  It just knows how to recursively split the iteration space.

Comment: By the way, instead of tbb::blocked_range<...>, you could use tbb::concurrent_vector<..>::range_type.  There is a method tbb::concurrent_vector<...>::range() that gives you a range over the entire concurrent_vector.